Identify film about an assassin with the word "Identity" in the title. NOT Bourne Identity
Trying to remember a movie I saw when I was a kid. Prob 70's or 80's.
There isn't  a lot of info on it that I can remember. One scene is at the end where a "glass house" blows up with the main bad guy inside. I think the good guy was an assassin of sorts who had brothers (not biological) like him, but then he turned on them all.
I think it may have the word "identity" in the title. I just watched the old  "The Bourne Identity" tv miniseries from 1988 and that is not it. That's pretty much all I remember.

Just out of pure curiosity, why are people downvoting this question? What's the reason for it? What's wrong with this question?

Brotherhood of the Rose (1989)
It was a TV mini-series about two spies (their codenames Romolus and Remus) who were taken from an orphanage and raised and trained by their handler, Robert Mitchum. He betrays them, kills one of them (David Morse), and the other (Peter Strauss) seeks revenge. At the end, as part of his revenge, he blows up his handler's glass house. 
Trailer:



At ca. 1:15 in the above trailer you can see the scene where Strauss blows up that glass house with the small plane. Near the end of the trailer, ca. at the 1:26 mark, there is another brief shot of the exploding glass house. And at the 0:38 mark in the trailer you can briefly see Robert Mitchum, the handler, in his glass house, opening a secret compartment under the roses where he keeps his compromising records on other people. 
From an IMDb plot summary:

"Romulus and Remus are two CIA agents, their direct instructor is
  John Elliott. They both were picked up at an orphanage by Elliott at
  the age of about eight, raised together as brothers and
  specially trained to supersede every other agent in the service."

There is no "Identity" in the title, but otherwise the movie fits your description. 

Your a legend. That looks like it alright. Never would have remembered it myself. Thank you so much. Been bothering me for years.
